# Filter items from two table. mysql normalization

Tags: mysql

Basically I want to select all the cars where car_color=yellow & car_gear=Manual. 
How can I achieve this? What shall I write instead of "???" ? 
Is my table construction wrong?

What I have done so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM
    A
JOIN 
    B
ON
    A.id=B.Aid WHERE ???";
```

Table A

```
id  title
1   Toyota
2   Volvo
```

Table B

```
id  Aid     attr_name   attr_val
0   1       car_year    2012
1   1       car_color   red
2   1       car_km      1000
3   1       car_gear    manual
4   2       car_color   black
5   2       car_km      0
6   2       car_gear    Automat
```

Comment: it sure looks like you need to redesign your table

Comment: is the statement not working without a where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is for you need to redesign your table if you want a `where` clause to work properly. Something like:

```
create table tableB
(
    id int,
    Aid int,
    car_year int,
    car_color varchar,
    car_km int,
    car_gear varchar
)
```

Then you can write your `SQL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
JOIN B
    ON A.id=B.Aid 
WHERE car_color='yellow'
    AND car_gear='Manual'
```

Or you could go even further where you create a separate table for each of the car variables - year, color, km, gear.  It really depends on what your needs are, you don't want to overkill it.

Comment: Now im sure that my table structure is wrong.But Lets say I add a cat to table A. and in table B I add cat_age=x cat_color=y. So now table A has both cats and cars. Must I create a diffrent table for each item type? or Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: it really depends on your needs, you could create one table that contains the car details (year, km, color) and a second table for the cat (age, color) and then you would just use a foreign key reference for each of them

Comment: happy to help, it sometimes just takes some time to figure out the best design